# format values rounded to zero with as blank

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to use a custom number format to format a cell with a value that is rounded to zero (but not quite zero) to be blank.

The format string I'm using currently testing is `#.###;-#.###;`, although that doesn't quite work (shown below with "x" used in the third block of the format string). I'd want -0.234 to be shown as blank, not as a cell containing only a minus sign.

[image]

What would be the proper way to achieve this, given that I need/want to set the number format externally (via another application)?

Comment: I was able to do what you're asking (I think) using a format of #,###;;x

Answer (score 0):

Each personalized format may have up to four sections, in the order:

```
<POSITIVE>;<NEGATIVE>;<ZERO>;<TEXT>
```

So, if you want a blank on negative numbers and an `x` in zero numbers, just type in:

```
#,###; #,###; ;x
```

(just check the comma/dot and the semicolon/comma for the regional language of your computer)

Also, have in mind that the number sign `#` displays only the significant digits in the number, whereas the the zero `0` displays also non-significant zeros. Just whatever fits best to you.

Comment: That unfortunately also leaves other negative numbers blank (-42, for example, should show up as -42).

Comment: then, put both the positive and negative numbers in the format. I edited my answer. check it

Comment: also, check if you want to display or not the minus sign before the negative number. If so, add the minus sign on the format: `#,###; -#,###; ;x`

Comment: I do want the minus sign shown before a negative number, but not before negative zero (a value less than zero, but greater than -0.5).

Comment: Then you need to format your numbers with [Conditional formatting](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-formulas-with-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f), because you want different criteria for the same type of number (i.e., for negative numbers, for example).

Comment: Add different formulas to your conditional formatting and format the numbers `<-0.5` with the negative sign, but the numbers on the range `-0.5<x<0` must be formatted without the negative sign